# Eclipse|Idea don't see a command line created project in theirt workspace?

Tags: android, eclipse, command-line, intellij-idea

Working under Linux Ubuntu  I have made a script which automates the creation and build of  new "Hello World" android projects in the workspace of Eclipse and/or Intellij Idea . 
The script also inserts my own icons into the different res/drawable directories and adjusts the AndroidManifest.xml to reflect this .
Alas none of these 2 ides recognizes the new project , I still have to import the project  (which is already in the workspace ) via "import project " working through a multitude of screens ?
( I'm new to Android and Ides , used to make C-programs all via command-line tools .)
Has anyone a suggestion ?
T.I.A

Answer (score 0):

I can answer your question specifically for IntelliJ IDEA and generally for other IDEs such as Eclipse and NetBeans.

The IDE needs configuration information beyond what's in the project's source code. It needs to know what JDK version to use, where the JDK is, what Android SDK to use, where it is, etc. In the case of IntelliJ IDEA, this is all stored in the either 1) the .idea directory (and its content) and an *.iml file for each module or 2) an *.ipr and *.iws file and an *.iml file for each module. Eclipse and NetBeans likewise use several configuration files. These files are very IDE specific (although IntelliJ IDEA can use and maintain eclipse configuration files.) The specifics of these files frequently change between versions. So even if you spent the hours (or more likely days or weeks) it would take to modify your script to create these configuration files, it would be one more thing to maintain.

My suggestion would be that instead of using your script, use the [maven-android-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/GettingStarted). It has several [Archetypes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html) available which can auto generate android projects. You can write your own Archetype that would include your files/icons and manifest modifications. You can run the Archetype from the command line (via mvn) or in IDEA, you can Select *File > New Project > Maven Module* and then select your Archetype. This would create your project and import it into the IDE in a single step. Plus using maven to manage your projects will make development much easier. Of course, there is an initial learning curve to learning maven, but it is so worth it.